# Windows won't sleep

Tags: windows, windows-8, sleep, power-management

My Windows 8.1 PC suddenly decided it no longer wants to go to sleep.  If I explicitly put it to sleep then it stays in sleep mode, but it doesn't obey the power plan setting to go to sleep after 30 minutes.

- Power plan (in Power Options) is Balanced
- `powercfg /requests` repots "none" for all categories
- I've disabled streaming in Windows Media Player
- Just to be sure, I've gone into *Power Options > Power plan settings > Advance power options > Multimedia settings > When sharing media* and selected *Allow the computer to sleep*

Any suggestions what else to fiddle with?  Is there anything I can look for in Event Viewer that might shed some light on the problem?

Comment: Make sure there's nothing in Task Scheduler that's waking up the system.  When I checked my Vista box, after I'd been using it for about a year, I discovered that several tools had installed tasks to check for updates, etc, and some were triggering every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is...  Something had turned on **Wake on Pattern Match** in the device settings for my Ethernet controller.

In addition to the steps I describe in the OP, I verified that there is nothing in Task Scheduler and I verified that none of my USB devices had a setting that would wake the system.  (Several USB devices have such as setting, but that setting is ghosted and not available to be enabled in all of them.)

I ran *msconfig* and rebooted with all non-essential services disabled.  The system slept like a baby.  After an exercise of turning services back on, I determined that the system wouldn't sleep if the *HomeGroup Provider* service is enabled.  Similarly, I discovered that with all of the services enabled, I could get the system to sleep if I left the HomeGroup and rebooted.  (Simply leaving the HomeGroup wasn't sufficient.)

So, now I knew that *HomeGroup prevented the PC from sleeping*.  After a bit more investigation, I determined that the underlying problem was that the *Wake on Pattern Match* setting had somehow become enabled.

EDIT:

Or not... Turning off the setting on the Ethernet controller device allows the PC to sleep if I reboot and just let it cook without logging in.  But once I log in, it stops sleeping.  So I'm making progress (I think), but there is still a problem...